# Using Git/Beanstalkapp, is it possible to track files locally, but not push to production (not using sub modules/separate repo)

Tags: git, git-tower

I'm using git-tower, obviously git, and Beanstalkapp. I have different branches for each version of my software. Inside this, I have an installer and upgrade files for each version that I use to repackage the software.

However, I don't want these installer files to be pushed to production, which is the live demo. This is because the installer files are not needed on a live version since it has already been installed. It's also a security risk.

How do I track changelogs, installer scripts/wizards, and upgrade scripts locally for packaging/versioning purposes, but not have it push to my live demos?

Note: I'd prefer not using a separate repo/sub modules as I don't really understand how that works and feel it'd complicate the process further. However, if either can be explained to show it would still be relatively simple and efficient, I'd consider it.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. Beanstalkapp has the ability to exclude files and directories from a deployment, so I can take care of it on their end.